We are migrating a VM from AWS to Azure and Azure site recovery tool package is not compatible with ubuntu 20.04
We are migrating a VM from AWS to Azure and  Azure site recovery tool package is not compatible with ubuntu 18.
root@ip-172-16-1-79:~# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
root@ip-172-16-1-79:~# uname-a
uname-a: command not found
root@ip-172-16-1-79:~# uname  -a
Linux ip-172-16-1-79 5.15.0-1068-aws #74~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 6 19:32:13 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@ip-172-16-1-79:~#

As per this Azure documentation above kernel  5.15.0-1068-aws is not compatible with ASR.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/vmware-physical-azure-support-matrix#ubuntu-kernel-versions
Could you please suggest which kernel version We need to use to meet the compatible requirements.
The installation of the mobility agent on Ubuntu 20.04 servers failed with the following error message:
"error_name":"ASRMobilityServiceKernelNotSupported",
"error_params":{"KernelVersion":"5.15.0-1068-aws"},
"default_message":"This version of mobility service doesn't support the operating system kernel version (5.15.0-1068-aws) running on the source machine. Please refer to the list of operating systems supported by Azure Site Recovery: https://aka.ms/asr-os-support"


What do you mean by Ubuntu 18? Are you running the desktop, server, or the IoT version? If you are running either the server or the desktop Ubuntu, edit your question and specify whether it is 18.04 or 18.10.

Why did you tag 20.04?

updated the question,the version we are using is ubuntu server 20.04.
